# If I rolled out an update to 10% of users, and update the app again, will it again choose the same 10% users?

Tags: android, google-play, crashlytics, google-play-console

Suppose I rolled out an update to 10% of the users. But there was some bug that was causing crashes. So, I updated the app again and rolled out 10% of the users. Will the Play Console again choose the same 10% of the users who were chosen before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is Yes, According to google docs when you perform a 10% staged rollout and then you release the new build in that case Google will target the same users.

Source:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en (Refer point 3)

Comment: In case something changes at that link, here's the text it says right now: "When you do a staged rollout of a new release before completing the rollout of the previous release, the new release will use the same group of users as the previous release (depending on the percentage of the rollout)."